# Can files and folders be excluded from processing in scct?

Tags: scala, sbt, scct

I would like to know if there is a way I can exclude files/folders from SCCT coverage just like in JaCoCO4SBT

```
jacoco.excludes in jacoco.Config := Seq("views*", "Routes", "controllers*routes*", "controllers*Reverse*", "controllers*javascript*", "controller*ref*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look at [the sources](https://github.com/mtkopone/scct/blob/master/src/main/scala/reaktor/scct/ScctInstrumentPlugin.scala) I don't think it's possible. The plugin doesn't seem to use sbt's settings and it's going to be tough to reconfigure it.